# Issue with string in MySQL query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

Two queries:

```
$reg_insert_basic_query = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO `Members` (username, password, email, api_key)
        VALUES ('$nuser', '$hash', '$nemail', '$napik');

    $gw2name        = "name.3245";
        $gw2_world_id   = $epa_array[0]['world'];
        $gw2_world_name = "'".$epw_array[0]['name']."'";
        $gw2name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $gw2name);

        $reg_insert_basic_query = <<<SQL
            INSERT INTO Members (gw2_name, WorldID, Worldname)
            VALUES ($gw2name, $gw2_world_id, $gw2_world_name)
        SQL;
            if(!$result = $mysqli->query($reg_insert_basic_query)){
                die('<br />There was an SQL error![' . $mysqli->error . ']');
            }
```

I figured using single quotes around the $gw2_name would work or double quotes, but nothing is working. I am not sure how to sanitize the period in "name.3245" for this to work.

Comment: this `($gw2name, $gw2_world_id, $gw2_world_name)` all needs to be quoted if they're strings `('$gw2name', '$gw2_world_id', '$gw2_world_name')` - `$mysqli->error` should have thrown you an error.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sdCGR5M.png It only created a new row for some reason.

Comment: I kidna realized my issue here, maybe the second query should be an update xD

Comment: as per your edit, you have spaces before your closing `SQL;` and they shouldn't be there. Error reporting would have thrown you a parse error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and your variables need to be quoted as stated above.

Comment: I don't know if it should be an update, should it?

Comment: you're using the 2x same query variables, only one will be done and you're missing a second identifier for your heredoc. You have 2x `<<<SQL` but only one `SQL;` and spaces before it. I don't know what else to say to help you out anymore than I already have. Keep checking for errors.

Comment: It's just the websites editor being weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$reg_insert_basic_query = <<<SQL
UPDATE `Members`
SET gw2_name = '$gw2name', WorldID = '$gw2_world_id', Worldname = '$gw2_world_name'
WHERE ID = '$u_id'
SQL;
```

Fixes the issue without a new row being created.