# Mysql check if email exists in database, keeps returning 0

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, heres an update. $userexists stays at 0. Even though the user DOES exist in the database. It should tick to 1 because the user exists.

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if ($email === ''){
    unset($email);
}
   $nemail = test_input($email);


$userexists=0;
$test = <<<SQL
SELECT email FROM `Members` WHERE email='$nemail'
SQL;
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($test)){
    die('There was an error running the query');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $nemail = $row['email'];
    $userexists==1;
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: check by print_r($sql).let me know it is returning

Comment: whatever's failing you, you didn't post.

Comment: btw, you have a question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34033996/ where you're using `mysqli_` and you're using `mysql_` in this one, why is that? you're not connecting with `mysqli_` now are you?

Comment: updated original post

Comment: now you went and changed your question completely. and no idea where your email variable's coming from.

Comment: and this is a syntax error `$userexists==1;` of sorts; remove an equal sign. we're not comparing here, you need to "assign". `$userexists=1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code `$userexists==1;`

Remove an equal sign. we're not comparing here, you need to "assign".

```
$userexists=1;
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Plus, the `test_input()` function you're using isn't the best to test against an SQL injection.

Use a prepared statement, please:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Heh, thanks! I missed that. Also loking over my code again im finding issues too. e.g. unset($email); and then proceeding to use it anyway...

Comment: @KevinK You're welcome Kevin, glad to have been of help. *Cheers* and do use a prepared statement. That function of yours won't protect you like a prepared statement, which I added to my answer. *Stay safe* ;-)